# What level of infinity is referred to when talking about recurring digits?

Tags: infinity, decimal-expansion

If a digit is written as $3.\dot{3}$, what level of infinity do the dots continue on for? Can this be proven to be true, or is it just a quirk of the notation?

More specifically, $1/3$ can obviously be broken up like

$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}{\frac{3}{10^n}}$$

However, I'm wondering what $\infty$ is actually meaning here. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The symbol $\infty$ in this notation reminds of the extra point in the one-point compactification of $\Bbb N$

Answer (score 6):

This means that there are *countably infinite* $3$'s after the one's digit.  We can see this with the base-$10$ expansion of $3.\dot{3}.$  We have

$$3.\dot{3} = 3.333\dotsc =  3 + \frac{3}{10} + \frac{3}{100} + \frac{3}{1000} + \dotsb = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{3}{10^{n}}.$$

Comment: So it could also be that there is $3.333\dots 3$? I mean, a sequence of length $\Bbb N\cup\{\Bbb N\}$ is countably infinite...

Comment: @AsafKaragila wouldn't that mean that it would be possible to rewrite $3.\dot{3}$ as $$\sum^{|\mathbb{N}|}_{n=0}{\frac{3}{10^n}}$$ in which case $$3\times\sum^{|\mathbb{N}|}_{n=0}{\frac{3}{10^n}}$$ would be a countable infinite sequence, so $$10 = 2\times\sum^{|\mathbb{N}|}_{n=0}{\frac{3}{10^n}}+\sum^{|\mathbb{N}|+1}_{n=0}{\frac{3}{10^n}}$$, yet since Euler's proof states that $9.\dot{9}=10$, $1=0$ at the top of the sum function in the last expression. This is the main reason I was confused about this in the first place, because this disproof is obviously wrong, yet so simply to follow.

Comment: @Geza: My point is that sequences are indexed by *ordinals* and not *cardinals*. The question is not "how many digits are there" but "how long is the sequence of digits".

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing to prove. That notations is just a convention for
$$
3.333\ldots
$$
which is in turn just
$$
\sum_{i=0}^\infty 3 \times 10^{-i}
=
3 + \frac{3}{10}
+ \frac{3}{100}
+ \frac{3}{1000} + \cdots
$$

The "$\infty$" is not a real number, nor even a cardinal number. It's part of the convention we use to write this sum of countably many real numbers, one for each natural number. You could equally well write
$$
\sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}}
$$
(since the order of summation does not matter for a sum of positive terms).

Comment: I've edited the question to make it a bit clearer.

Comment: @GezaKerecsenyi See my edit.